# Qt QMessageBox center 'critical' in desktop

Tags: c++, qt, qmessagebox

The critical method of QMessageBox has 4 overridden methods, it also has individual methods for setting the title, message text and parent.

I want to display a critical error dialog in the center of the desktop.  I have the desktop geometry, what I need is the geometry of the message box so I can apply it to the desktop geometry to center the error dialog.

But its a chicken and egg, I can't get the error dialog before it's rendered for positioning, so how do I do this?  I don't want to have to resort to magic numbers to apply an offset.

Comment: Checkout the values returned by the sizeHint() method. It should give you the size of the msg box before rendering it.

Comment: @GabriellaGiordano, the issue is that there is no critical method without the parameters and I tried calling sizeHint, it didn't help, I subtract this geometry from the desktop, but when calling critical the dialog still appears top left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual solution was a lot simpler, just removing the parent parameter from the call to critical has the exact desired effect:

```
    const QString csMsg("\'" + strConfig + "\' does not exist!");
    const QString csTitle("Error");
    QMessageBox msgBox;
    msgBox.critical(nullptr, csTitle, csMsg);
    QApplication::quit();
```

Comment: Note that `critical` is a static method, so you don't need an instance. Simply call `QMessageBox::critical(nullptr, "title", "message");`

Answer (score -1):

This should center the dialog on the primary desktop, but I did not test it on multiple screen setup.

```
 QMessageBox message(QMessageBox::Critical, QObject::tr("Error!"),
                     QObject::tr("This is a critical error!"),
                     QMessageBox::Ok,
                     QApplication::desktop()); 
 message.exec();
```

EDIT
It is indeed one of the constructors of QMessageBox, as user Scheff correctly pointed out. This solution exploits Qt's default behavior of centering dialogs w.r.t. the parent widget.

Sometimes, I found that on some platforms, providing a null parent will not center a dialog on the screen because different window decorators may adopt different policies for dialog positioning. Forcing the desktop widget to be the parent fixed the issue 100% of the times for me.

Anyway, whatever works is good :)

Comment: I cannot find a prototype that matches your suggestion.

Comment: @SPlatten _I cannot find a prototype that matches your suggestion._: This constructor should match [`QMessageBox::QMessageBox()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmessagebox.html#QMessageBox-1).